# Connect to Azure devops repo using sourcetree on MacOS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I've created a new project on azure devops and now I'm trying to add an account to sourcetree:

I've setup the opions in the following way:

Host: Azure devops

Link next to Host: https://myuser@dev.azure.com/myuser
Also tried with https://dev.azure.com/myuser

Auth Type: It's locked to private token, can't change it.

Username: Tried with my email, also enabled alternative credentials and tried with that username.

Password: Tried with the real password as well as the personal access token

Protocol: HTTPS

I keep getting the error: `We couldn't connect to Azure DevOps with your credentials.` What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Issue tracker for this issue - go vote it up and it's more likely to get fixed https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-10800

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although SourceTree for macOS has updated the name of Azure DevOps (from "Visual Studio Team Services"), it appears that it does not support the new Azure DevOps URLs.

You can use the old-format (VSTS-style) URLs.  Instead of `https://dev.azure.com/username`, you can use `https://username.visualstudio.com`.

[image: SourceTree]

Ironically, it seems that SourceTree for Windows still calls the product "Visual Studio Team Services" but supports the new-style Azure DevOps URLs.)

Comment: At the time of writing this comment (23.0.2019) the Windows version is working with the old link _only_, and not with the new one (dev.azure...).

Comment: It's worth mentioning this method doesn't work if you have sub repositories and SSH, as it will also try to use a visual studio URL to resolve the sub repositories which will be expected in visual studio format, unless you adapt your subrepo clone urls to visual studio style from the default git@ssh.dev.azure.com format. Which I'm not sure how they look in visual studio style then you're stuck. Waiting on a fix for Azure Devops URLs..

Comment: As of today (On Windows) for me `username.visualstudio.com` doesn't work, but `orgname.visualstudio.com` works.

Comment: Host: orgname.visualstudio.com

username: My.long.emailAddress@someorg.gov

Auth: PAT
Protocol: HTTPS

Answer (score 8):

I was successful with *Preferences/Accounts/Azure DevOps*

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/
{username}
{token}
HTTPS
```

and using this remote url

```
https://{username}@dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{projectname}/_git/{repository}
```

Comment: After two hours of trying, this worked for me. It was the username in the remote URL that did the trick. Sad that this is still a problem in 2023.

Answer (score 4):

After much experimentation this was my experience from today:

- You need to create a DevOps Personal Access Token for authentication, SourceTree can't authenticate with your normal Azure username/password combination.

  - Create a PAT using the following procedure, [Use personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate#create-a-pat)
- Remove any DevOps-related entries displayed in SourceTree > Preferences > Accounts.
- In the properties of the local SourceTree repo > Settings > Remotes > origin enter:

  - URL / Path: `https://{yourAzureUsernameOrEmailAddress}@dev.azure.com/{orgName}/{projectName}/_git/{repoName}`

    - **IMPORTANT**: If yourAzureUsernameOrEmailAddress is an email address be sure to replace its `@` symbol with the `%40` URI encoding otherwise it will send the domain-portion as your username. e.g.: `https://foo%40example.com@dev.azure.com/...`
  - Host Type: `Unknown`

Now when you Pull/Push/Fetch you should see a "Password Required" dialog "For user yourAzureUsernameOrEmailAddress on host dev.azure.com":

- Password: `{yourPersonalAccessToken}`

Be sure to enter your PAT, not your password.

It should be successful and if you elected to "Store Password in Keychain" then you should be able to go to Keychain Access > login > Passwords and see and entry for `dev.azure.com Access Key for yourAzureUsernameOrEmailAddress` listed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a Personal Access Token.

[The below is from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts)

Personal access tokens (PATs) are alternate passwords that you can use to authenticate in to Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server (TFS). In this article, we walk you through how to create or revoke PATS.

Azure DevOps Services and TFS use enterprise-grade authentication to help protect and secure your data. Clients like Visual Studio and Eclipse (with the Team Explorer Everywhere plug-in) also support Microsoft account and Azure AD authentication.

For non-Microsoft tools that integrate into Azure DevOps but don't support Microsoft account or Azure AD authentication, you must use PATs. Examples include Git, NuGet, or Xcode. To set up PATs for non-Microsoft tools, use Git credential managers or create them manually.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I did try it using a PAT in the password field.

Comment: You are quite right, its not working. I get a VS30063 "You are not authorised to access <my devops url>". Maybe log an issue?

Comment: Absolutely no clue. You are thinking it might be from them?

Comment: Quite possibly, I am on windows and likely a different version too.

Comment: You can also just open against a local clone of your repo in the mean time

Comment: I was setting up a new project, so there is no local clone or anything yet. Just wanted to get something connected to it :(

Answer (score 2):

My experience on MacOS and devops was:

1. Delete recent password/key on keychain access.
2. Try to pull again, sourcetree will ask for password.
3. Input your PAT you got from your account on devops, and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to:

1. generate the PAT
2. In Sourcetree, add a new account with the PAT as username AND as password
3. If Sourcetree seems to be making you struggle (caching or not picking the right account if you have multiple) just add :yourorgname.visualstudio.com/projectname

*PS: I wrote a post on this ([this one](https://medium.com/p/connecting-atlassian-sourcetree-with-your-azure-devops-git-repo-b88aeab91b00)), check it out if you want the full details.*

Comment: This one works as of may 10th, 2021, when connecting an account. Tested on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

After surfing entire internet I found the answer.

Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=preview-page) and at Point 4., remember to add **expiration date**. By default it selects existing date, you need to select expiration date. It was this place where I did not select expiration date and it keeps throwing login error message.

I selected 1year from today as expiration date, **Full Access** under **Scopes**.

Your clone > HTTPS Link wont work. 
[Like this URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRFIq.png)

Follow @Edward Thomson format to input URL

**Username**: Your generated Token

**Password**: Your generated Token (same as Username)

OR

**Username**: Your email to Azure DevOps

**Password**: Your generated Token

@taigi100 You can delete token by selecting **revoke** on Azure DevOps

@taigi100 @Murray Foxcroft - Hope this helps.