# How to activate "Alternate credentials" on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I just created a new organization for my team on Azure DevOps. I wanted to activated the git access through username/password to begin with(for multiple reasons: We use Https, so no ssh certificate, and I've no idea how to use PAT with our current git client(sourcetree)).

Currently, when I go in my settings on "Alternate credentials", I get this:

[image]

But I've been into the organization page and I cannot find this settings? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I've been into the organization page and I cannot find this
> settings? How can I enable it?

You can't enable that, the `Alternate authentication credentials` setting has been removed from Organization `settings=>Policies` for **newly created organizations**. Check [the blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-will-no-longer-support-alternate-credentials-authentication/) shared above in **Michael's** answer.

> I've no idea how to use PAT with our current git client.

It's recommended to use PAT instead since you have no SSH certificate. Here're samples about how to use `git+pat` **without** pop-up window for credentials (Useful when you're running the commands in pipeline, since you can't enter credentials if there's pop-up window):

1.You can generate Git credentials to get temp username and password, and then use format:

```
git clone https://UserName:Password@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName
```

2.You can [create a limited PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-a-pat)(more secure then Full access) and use command:

[image]

```
git clone https://anything:{yourPAT}@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName
```

Same format when using `git push`...

Also you can clone the repo with git clone + URL from [this button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#get-the-clone-url-to-your-repo). Per my experience, it will prompt for credentials and save the credentials in local machine.

**For Source Tree:**

```
Url: https://OrganizationName.visualstudio.com

userName: The email address of your azure devops account

password: PAT
```

[image]

[image]

Enter correct URL format, click the refresh PAT button and enter the email as username, PAT as password. The authentication succeeds in my source tree for windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm struggling to see what would be my username with the PAT, any idea how to do this? Also, the team is using SourceTree, my understand is that the PAT should be the password but again, what would be the username here?

Comment: @J4N You don't need the username when using PAT. Per my experience, the PAT contains the info about username+password, it's not just password. So you can try combinations like: UserName:PAT+Password:PAT or UserName:EmailAddress+Password:PAT, can it work?

Comment: @J4N I'm not using Source tree, you may also get some help from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239179/10910450). Maybe the url should be: `https://dev.azure.com/OrganizationName` or `https://OrganizationName.visualstudio.com`, let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like effective March 2, 2020 Alternate Credentials are no longer supported. Organizations created before then can use them for a short time to transition to PATs. New organizations do not have that option. [Source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-will-no-longer-support-alternate-credentials-authentication/)

From Microsoft DevBlog:

### Deprecation Timeline

- Beginning December 9, 2019 we will disable and hide Alternate Credentials settings for organizations that don’t have Alternate Credentials set. This change will be in effect for all these organizations by December 20, 2019.
- In the coming months we will work with our customers that are still using the feature, to help them switch to another, more secure authentication method.
- March 2, 2020 – Start gradually disabling Alternate Credentials for all Azure DevOps organizations.

### Legacy Organizations

If you have a legacy organization, the option would appear under Organization Settings, Policies (under the Security subheading). The toggle is called "Alternate authentication credentials"

[image: screenshot of legacy security policy menu here]